# how to fix nextjs prerender error - vercel deployment?

Tags: next.js, vercel, contentful

How do I troubleshoot this problem this deployment issue? I am following this tutorial. My node_modules and .next are ignored and not pushed to github. It works locally but can't seem to deploy. I have supplied both the component code as well as the page it's exported on. Let me know if you can see what I am missing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4SVNleMitE

deployment errors

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/components/BlogPosts". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined
    at BlogPosts (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/130.js:39:12)
    at d (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at Object.renderPage (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:673:46)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:315:51)
    at Function.getInitialProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_document.js:645:16)
    at Object.loadGetInitialProps (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/utils.js:69:29)
```

---

component blog posts

```
export default function BlogPosts({post }) {
   
   const {title, information,slug , thumbnail} = post.fields
   
    return (
        <div>
        
      
            <div className='container w-50 h-25 mt-4'>
                <Image
                    className='nav' 
                    src={'https:' + thumbnail.fields.file.url}
                    width={thumbnail.fields.file.details.image.width}
                    height={thumbnail.fields.file.details.image.height}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h4 className=''>{title}</h4>
                    <Link href={'/contentslug/' + slug}>
                        <a className='btn btn-primary text-white'>Read more</a>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Pages/Posts

```
import {createClient} from 'contentful'
import BlogPosts from './components/BlogPosts'
import Nav from './components/Nav'
import Logo from './components/Logo'


export async function getStaticProps() {

  const client = createClient({
    space: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_TOKEN,
  })

const res = await client.getEntries({content_type: 'posts'})

return {
  props: {
    posts: res.items ,
    revalidate: 1
  }
}


}



export default function Home({posts}) {
 console.log(posts);
  
  return (
    
    <div>
     <Logo/> 
    <Nav/>
    <div className="container text-center display-5">
   {posts.map(post => (
    <BlogPosts key={post.sys.id} post={post}/>
           
   ))}

</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you have both environment variables configured in Vercel?

Comment: yes both are configured.

Answer (score 0):

You have `fields` of `undefined`. this might be caused because of some strange deploying behavior if you are 100% sure your code works.

How to fix (probably):

1. Build your project locally. if it works, follow the next step
2. Comment your code in `BlogPosts`, inside the exported component. The code must work, so your exported component will be `empty` but `working`.
3. Push this code to Vercel.
4. Uncommit your code. (done at point 2)
5. Push again.

P.S. this behavior with API is sometimes caused because of API middleware you reworked.

Comment: commented it out and it threw an error locally. Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: i've added both the component code and the page it's exported on.

Comment: Which version of node are you using?

Comment: I am using version 16.13.0

Comment: still not working, any idea?

Comment: Replace all childs with `?.` instad of ` .`   Example: `thumbnail.fields.file.details.image.width` to `thumbnail?.fields?.file?.details?.image?.width`
You have error with values during page render

Answer (score 0):

This question helped me: [NextJS Prerender Error - Works fine in Dev, breaks in Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71002100/nextjs-prerender-error-works-fine-in-dev-breaks-in-build). When using NextAuth.js, I had to use the following snippet:

```
const d = useSession();
let data = null;
if (d) data = d.data;
```

I don't know why this works, but it may have something to do with SWC.