# NextJS Prerender Error - Works fine in Dev, breaks in Build

Tags: next.js

I am building a NextJS application and everything is working fine locally. It pulls in all of the data and throws no error.

However, when I try to run `npm run build`, I get a Prerender Error. I have tried to follow the instructions in [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error), but I didn't find it very helpful.

Could the problem be that I'm importing the posts using `path.join(process.cwd(), './posts')` and in this case, when it builds, the paths are somehow different than in development? I can't think of anything else that could be missing.

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  ....
}
```

Full error:

```js
Error occurred prerendering page "/blog/Blog". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined
    at Post (/.next/server/chunks/2648.js:223:21)
    at d (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at renderPage (/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:736:46)
    at Object.ctx.renderPage (/.next/server/pages/_document.js:77:26)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:368:51)
    at Function.getInitialProps (/.next/server/chunks/6859.js:651:16)
postdirectory /posts
```

Here is my file structure:

```
lib
 ┗ posts.js
pages
 ┣ blog
 ┃ ┣ Blog
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.tsx
 ┃ ┣ Hero
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.tsx
 ┃ ┗ [slug].tsx
 ┣ knowledge
 ┃ ┣ components
 ┃ ┃ ┣ BlogSection
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ components
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ ArticleBox
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃  ┗ ArticleBox.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ index.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Hero
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ index.tsx
 ┃ ┗ index.tsx
 ┣ _app.css
 ┣ _app.tsx
 ┣ _document.tsx
 ┗ index.tsx
posts
 ┣ post_1.md
 ┣ post_2.md
 ┣ post_3.md
```

pages/blog/[slug].tsx

```js
import { getAllPostIds, getPostData, getSortedPostsData } from '../../lib/posts';
import React from 'react';
import Hero from './Hero';
import BlogSection from './Blog';

export interface Props {
    postData: {...},
    posts: {...}[]
}

const BlogArticle: React.FC<Props> = ({ postData, posts }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Hero />
            <BlogSection postData={postData} posts={posts} />
        </>
    );
};

export default BlogArticle;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = await getAllPostIds();
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    return {
        props: {
            postData: await getPostData(params.slug),
            posts: await getSortedPostsData()
        }
    }
}
```

lib/posts.js

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import matter from 'gray-matter'

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), './posts')

export async function getSortedPostsData() {
    const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)
    const allPostsData = fileNames.map(fileName => {
        const slug = fileName.replace(/\.md$/, '')

        const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, fileName)
        const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8')

        const matterResult = matter(fileContents)

        return {
            slug,
            ...matterResult.data
        }
    })
}

export async function getAllPostIds() {
    const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)

    return fileNames.map(fileName => {
        return {
            params: {
                slug: fileName.replace(/\.md$/, '')
            }
        }
    })
}

export async function getPostData(slug) {
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${slug}.md`)
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8')
    const { data: frontmatter, content } = matter(fileContents)

    return {
        slug,
        content,
        frontmatter
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please add what exactlly the npm run build does? (Copy the build command from package.json)

Comment: Hi TDiblik. Thanks for your question! I have added it to the post. `npm run build` just runs `next build` . Let me know if you would like more details :)

Comment: To be honest, I can't figure out why is your implementation failing, however, I've found [example from Vercel](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/blog-starter) that does exactly what you're trying to do, I would suggest you to take a look at it :). If you have this code open sourced (checked your github, but couldn't find this example), I would be more than happy to debug this issue and open a pr fixing this

Comment: Thanks @TDiblik! I'll check it out :) Unfortunately, I can't make the whole repo public :(  Sorry!

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't help a whole lot, if you have any other issues, please let me know and I'll try to answer them (not really experienced when it comes to next js, but I've encountered some errors before :D)

Comment: Sometimes it turns out to be due to different VPN configurations between your local machine & the server if APIs are restricted to a specific domain/configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @TDiblik for pointing me in the right direction. As he mentioned, there is a [good example from Vercel](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/blog-starter).

One thing that I noticed that I did not do was add a way to handle the situation in which the post data was not available. In this case, I needed to add the following within the default exports for each page / component that was receiving the data.

```
    const router = useRouter()
    if (!router.isFallback && !post) {
        return <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />
    }
```

In this case, my pages/blog/[slug].tsx should look like:

```
import { getAllPostIds, getPostData, getSortedPostsData } from '../../lib/posts';
import React from 'react';
import Hero from './Hero';
import BlogSection from './Blog';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import ErrorPage from 'next/error'

export interface Props {
    postData: {...},
    posts: {...}[]
}

const BlogArticle: React.FC<Props> = ({ postData, posts }) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    if (!router.isFallback && !postData && !posts) {
        return <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Hero />
            <BlogSection postData={postData} posts={posts} />
        </>
    );
};

export default BlogArticle;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = await getAllPostIds();
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    return {
        props: {
            postData: await getPostData(params.slug),
            posts: await getSortedPostsData()
        }
    }
}
```

With this change, I was able to build the project.